# What is the equivalent of twiddle-wakka (~>) from ruby's gem in requirements.txt for python's pip?

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I've seen the twiddle-wakka operator (~>) used in ruby's gem file ([documentation](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/16)) to specify the last point version compatible like this:

```
'~> 0.3.1' is satisfied by 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, etc.
'~> 0.3.1' is not satisfied by 0.3.0
'~> 0.3' is satisfied by 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.5.1, etc.
'~> 0.3' is not satisfied by 0.2.0, 0.2.1, etc.
```

I see that there's a `>=` operator in the `requirements.txt` that can be used to specify anything better than that, but I'm hoping to avoid any future package updates (major version updates) not being backwards compatible with my code already -- hence why I want a twiddle-wakka.

Is there an equivalent operator in for pip?

Comment: Your examples are a bit strange.  Are you saying that, for instance, `~> 0.3.1` is  *not* satisifed by 0.4?

Comment: @BrenBarn correct. `~>` looks at the least significant version identifier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Someday it will be `~=` the [compatible-release operator specified by PEP 440](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#compatible-release), but none of the common Python tooling supports it yet—not pip, nor the newly-reborn [setuptools unfork](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools).

For now you’ll have to manually specify it, e.g.,

```
Django >= 1.4.3, < 1.5
```

Comment: Is this syntax acceptable as well? `Django >= 1.4.3, == 1.4.*`

Comment: It appears it's not compatible yet with `pip 1.3.1`.

Comment: @Nitrodist No, pip doesn’t seem to handle wildcards either. `>=` and `<` do work though. It’s a mess but it’s definitely getting better, and now that there are [proper specs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/) that will eventually be implemented, it will someday be great.